# OpenCL: know local work group size in advance?

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I'm working on optimizing a separable image downscaler.  My next step is reduction of multiple samplings (nearest) of the same texel by reading all necessary texels into local memory.  Here begins the fun...

The downscaler is versatile, so it can downscale anything larger into anything smaller and even take sections of an image and downscale it into a destination image.  Thus the final resolution divider never is a whole number.  Most of the time it will be something around 3.97 or such.  This means: I do not know the required size for that local array at compile time.

To me that means: before enqueuing a task, I'll have to create a local mem object of the required size.

How do I know what workgroup sizes OpenCL will select?

If there is no way, is there a "best practice" to overcome this problem?

P.S.: I'm writing for OpenCL 1.1 compatibility.

Comment: You can explicitly control the workgroup size, which would solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so.  The versatility can lead to indivisible sizes (i.e. a prime number) in any direction.  Thus - as OpenCL 1.1 does not allow a given local work dim not being a divisor of the corresponding global work dim - I cannot succeed like that.

Comment: You'll need to pad your global work dimensions to be a multiple of the workgroup size, and if necessary implement any special casing for the edge conditions. (Although it's usually more efficient to pad the data structures instead.)

Comment: Yeah, I started implementing this yesterday.  The problem with padding is that the destination data structure is an image2d_t, thus I need to omit writing over bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using images, the texture cache can be relied upon instead of using shared local memory.

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to answer the question myself.  As you tell, profiling showed a straight performance drop when trying to read all necessary pixels into local memory.  Obviously the texture cache really makes those multiple reads act just like local memory.  Thus in my test I just added overhead for sampling into local memory.  Also I increased the local mem pressure a lot - which could've caused another part of the slowdown (nearly factor 4).